# asp.net mvc 6 await SaveChangesAsync() not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Member Model:

```
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

with this dbcontext class:

```
   public class App1Context: DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
```

after migrations and making database I use a controller (Register) to save my new member data to database:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind("ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Pass")] Member member)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                App1context.Members.Add(member);
                await App1context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("showMember");
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes.");
        }
        return View(member);
    }
```

when system want execute [`await App1context.SaveChangesAsync();`] ,cannot save and `catch (DbUpdateException)`instead run.

why can't save??

Comment: so why you didn't add a message error ?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else has been defined, your ID on member will be assigned as the Primary Key of your table; Entity Framework will also assign it as auto increment(identity).

If you try to insert your own ID in your objects with identity enabled, and save them to the database; you will get an INSERT exception.

If this is the case, remove the ID from your BIND[] parameter, and EF will do it by it self.